# Creating product to be sold to public using prebuilt modules

Tags: arduino, certification, module, legal

Is it ok for me to combine multiple prebuilt modules, put them into casing and sell them to public? such as

(accelerometer) https://core-electronics.com.au/adxl335-triple-axis-accelerometer-gy-61.html

(arduino) https://core-electronics.com.au/arduino-uno-r3.html

(bluetooth module) https://core-electronics.com.au/bluetooth-module-hc-06.html

Would I need to obtained certifications? what kind of certification would I need?

Comment: First determine exactly what modules and other circuitry will be required. "Such as" is not a good term to use when asking engineering questions. Need for some combination of agency certification, 3rd party certification, self certification, and ongoing manufacturing inspections is likely required for sale in most parts of the world. First decide how many products you think you can make and sell and where you might sell them. Then study the requirements and consider consulting an agency that provides certification assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I need to obtained certifications?

Yes, you will need to fullfill whatever requirements there are for the market you intend to sell your product.

For example. CE marking for EU, FCC certification for USA etc.

It does not matter that your product is made from "prebuilt modules", as it is your final product that need to be assessed.

In some ways on some markets, some module certification can be re-used by you which can make it somewhat easier/cheaper, common practice for RF modules. But you will still need to consider EMC, product safety, possibly some extra RF testing etc.

Comment: You probably mean UL/CSA for USA.  FCC only regulates radio frequency emission, there's still safety.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica As OP mentions a Bluetooth module, FCC is certainly needed. I did not intend to make an exclusive list of every certification needed, there is indeed more to it.

Comment: Meeting UL standards is important for the USA because they are safety standards. UL standard certification can be done by UL, ETL, CSA and others. It is important to note that ongoing periodic inspections of manufacturing is required for that and certification of the individual modules is not sufficient. For FCC, certification of the individual components may be sufficient.